# Google Analytics source

Tags: google-analytics, localhost

In my Google Analytics dashboard I have below referrer, can you please tell me where these came from?

```
localhost:16114 / referral
localhost:22218 / referral
```

Is it that someone trying on their system locally and clicking from that page to redirect to my site or what? also *Bounce Rate* of traffic from there sources is 100%! Is it some kind of bot or what?

Answer (score 1):

It could be there is link to your site on someones website. And they have version (maybe a development version), running on they're local machine. And they clicked it accidentally a couple times.

Another scenario could be that someone used curl or wget to to request resources from your server?

And finally, maybe just someone spoofing?